# Coin change problem in C++ stuck on recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to write a recursiive solution to the coin change problem in C++.
The problem provides a set of coins of different values and a value representing a sum to be paid.
The problem asks to provide the number of ways in which the sum can be paid given the coinages at hand.

I am stuck on this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

long recursive(int amount, vector<long>& input_vector, long ways, vector<long>::const_iterator current) { 
    if (amount < 0)
        return ways;
    for (auto iter = current; iter != input_vector.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << "amount: " << amount << ", current coin: " << *iter << '\n';
        ways += recursive(amount - *iter, input_vector, 0, iter);
        cout << "ways: " << ways << '\n';
    }
    return ways;
}

long getWays(int n, vector<long> c) {
    sort(c.begin(), c.end(), greater<long>());
    
    return recursive(n, c, 0, c.begin());
}

int main() {
    int amount = 32;
    vector<long> coinages = {2, 5, 6, 10};
    
    cout << "Solution is: " << getWays(amount, coinages) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The answer should be 27, but I get 0?
Even if I omit the eturn 0 at the end of the main program, I still get 0.
So I'm kind of frustrated my logic does not work here and I'm clueless about how to solve this in a different way.

Comment: All your code paths leave `ways` at the 0 it receives, so there is nothing that would ever increment it

Comment: hello, thank you. It becomes vector c when I use the coins

Comment: no I increment ways insde the recursive function

Comment: and yet `cout << "ways: " << ways << '\n';` always prints 0 - so I'll claim that you are wrong with your claim that it is incremented

Comment: If you always pass in 0 for `ways`, what's the point of passing it at all?

Comment: ?? how can i solve it?

Comment: at each recursion, ways resets to 0 for that recursion, but when recursions unwind the ways for each recursion gets summed up to the previous recursion

Comment: Have you been introduced to debuggers? Being able to execute a program at your speed and watch exactly what happens in the program as it happens quickly disabuses any faulty assumptions that have been made.

Comment: yes i know debvuggers

Comment: That may be what you want to happen, but why waste the overhead and add noise by passing it? Just make a local variable and initialize it to zero.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Look at the recursive exit condition. It returns `ways`, which can be no value other than 0. So the caller will add 0 to its 0 and get 0. Then it will return 0 to its caller, which will sum up another 0. Ultimately the function cannot return anything but 0.

Comment: if I don'5t do that but put the exit condition at the end of the function I am stuck in an infinite recursion loop

Comment: Every time you hit the end of the line and can actually make change, you have found 1 way. 1 appears to be a better value to return, if you have actually found a valid way to make change. If not, then return 0.

Comment: if I write return amount == 0; is what you say? still return 0 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `amount` is 0, this is an answer, `return 1` to be added to `ways`. If you got below 0, dead end street, `return 0`, nothing will be added.

```
if (amount == 0)
    return 1;
if (amount < 0)
    return 0;
```

Comment: thank you. Doesn't work :(

Comment: How could it be, if it works for me? [gotbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dYqEesY7K)

Comment: do you get 27? please post all the code.

Comment: You had a link to it in my comment. 27 at the end.

Comment: yes but your code is 4 lines I tired to insert it in mine but it doesn't output 27

Comment: Does the link works for you https://godbolt.org/z/dYqEesY7K ?

Comment: Thaks man! I see it. You put those lines on top while I substituted them to the last return statement and that is why it did not work

Comment: That's great news!